# Remove a word in a String

Tags: vb.net, string, visual-studio-2008

I have problem in removing word in my array because it is a generated GUID.
And now I need is to remove 1 of word or item in that string.

Here is my String:

```
Dim guid_id as string ='3a0eed1f-73b2-11e0-8670-88006707ed92','3a125s34-73b2-11e0-8670-88006707ed92','3a112w3s-73b2-11e0-8670-88006707ed92'
```

Q: How can i remove the word or string `" '3a112w3s-73b2-11e0-8670-88006707ed92' "` in that 1 whole string?
I have idea that I need to convert it into List(of String) but I don't know how to remove it in that list.

Comment: find the start and end index of this word from string try to get rest of string using subString().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply find and replace the string using `Replace` function

```
Dim guid_id as string = "'3a0eed1f-73b2-11e0-8670-88006707ed92','3a125s34-73b2-11e0-8670-88006707ed92','3a112w3s-73b2-11e0-8670-88006707ed92'"

Dim strRemove As String = "'3a112w3s-73b2-11e0-8670-88006707ed92'"
guid_id = guid_id.Replace(strRemove, "").Trim()
If guid_id.Subtring(0,1) = "," Then   guid_id = guid_id.Substring(1);
If guid_id.Subtring(guid_id.Length-1) = "," Then   guid_id = guid_id.Substring(0, guid_id.Length-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

.NET Framework has an engine for text processing, which is represented by the System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex. You can use it to replace a specific word in a string. 
Try this code:

```
    Dim guid_id As String = "'3a0eed1f-73b2-11e0-8670-88006707ed92','3a125s34-73b2-11e0-8670-88006707ed92','3a112w3s-73b2-11e0-8670-88006707ed92'"

    Dim strRemove As String = "'3a112w3s-73b2-11e0-8670-88006707ed92'"

    'To remove strRemove from string, we use Regex replace method
    Dim regex = New Regex(strRemove, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    guid_id = regex.Replace(guid_id, "")

    'Now we remove 'Comma' from string, if it is needed.
    If guid_id.Subtring(0, 1) = "," Then guid_id = guid_id.Substring(1)
    If guid_id.Subtring(guid_id.Length - 1) = "," Then guid_id = guid_id.Substring(0, guid_id.Length - 1)
```